# ASP.net MVC 2 RenderAction with model throws URI too long exception

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, uri, rtf

In ASP.net MVC 2, I am using Html.RenderAction to render a partial view, RenderAction takes a Model as a parameter, code below.

```
<% Html.RenderAction("ReviewPartial", review); %>
```

And the controller action looks something like following

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Super User")]
public ActionResult ReviewPartial(Review review)
```

The review object can contain some rich text data in one of its properties, for the most part it works fine but if the data is too long it gives an error "URI too long"

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there's nothing that can really be done about this. Child actions, as currently implemented function as normal actions for the most part. When you pass a full model as a parameter to your child action, it is actually serializing the model to a string and attaching it as a querystring parameter. So, even though no real URL is ever exposed, the URL being generated and retrieved under the hood exceeds the maximum bounds.

You best bet is to simply don't ever pass full models to a child action. Instead pass just the id or similar and then look it up inside the child action.

Comment: Thanks Chris, thanks for that confirmation, I was already headed towards the id based solution.